# Repository or Service to insert data in database - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What do I use to create a new Address using Entity Framework:

Op1:

```
IRepository<Address> _addressRepository;
```

And talk directly to the Database using the the Address Entity.

Op2:

```
public bool CreateAddress(AddressDto addressDto);
```

And talk to the service method to insert a new Address.

The question is, in a long turn maintenance of the project, which one gives more guarantees of not existing the risk of someone change something and break another piece of code that depends on it?

Based on your experience, which one is the best approach?

Comment: I would the `Repository` just let do the database jobs, and the `Service` could do validation etc. If it implements an interface, you are very flexible.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Are you refering to what interface? Service or Repository?

Comment: Service. Using an interface for the `Repository<T>` like you do seems obvious to me, though Entity Framework might be flexible with database systems. If you use the repo just for database access and the services for business logic, I would definitively make use of interfaces. Of course it depends of the project. But imagine a framework which should be used and extended in many differnt projects. Without interfaces for the service layer you are dead in those scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the second option works best. I love to have a service façade, behind which business logic can be implemented and adapted in a way that will not affect the consumers of my services. Services, by the way, can be things like domain services, web services, Web API. Basically it is a shell around business logic and data access that just exposes methods that some consumer can call.

Exposing a repository method in my view gives away too much. Why would a consuming layer know about a repository implementation? And you will be tied to the repository pattern forever. There's been a lot of discussion about EF and (generic) repositories. Personally, I hate generic repositories. I like to think in terms of aggregate roots. Having a repository for each entity type is often one layer too much, it only gets in the way. `DbSet`s in a `DbContext` are basic repositories. The context suits itself perfectly as a unit of work. I tend to turn to contexts directly in service methods, in stead of orchestrating repositories and units of work. You *can* use repositories, of course, but hide them behind a service façade.

One final remark: I would not return just a boolean from a service method, but an object that contains information about failure/success of the method. E.g. a HttpResponse in Web API.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I think you may be right. Let say that service is the door to manipulate everything about an Entity, and this Service use the repository to manipulate everything about database operations. Btw, any post where I can get more info about a good practice to manage return method objects? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, no. I just learned it the hard way I guess. Maybe Dino Esposito's _Architecting Applications for the Enterprise_ educated me here, I don't remember.

Comment: And you build a Service Method for every operation like Details and Edit or general ones like GetById for Details and Edit?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Repository like this:

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public Repository(DbContext dataContext)
    {
        DbSet = dataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    #region IRepository<T> Members

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And when you need a new instance of Adress, just call your Repository to do this for you:

```
var adressRepository = new Repository<Adress>(yourDataContext);
```

With the AdressRepository just do:

```
adressRepository.Insert(yourAdressObject)
```

Finally call SaveChanges of your context :

```
yourDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Patrick knows how to work with Entity Framework. His question was just about architecture/design, not the implementation. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Davi, yes Linus is correct, the question is more about a conceptual ideia of what is more flexible in a long term project, but thank you for the answer.